# Why is my loop not getting past the first line in my file?

Tags: bash

script is as follows:

```
filename="/Users/ra222c/bkdockerhosts"

cat "$filename" | while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  echo $p
  out=$(ssh "$p" "df -h | awk '/disk-name/ {print \$5}' | sed 's/%//'")
  if [ $out -le 85 ]; then
    echo $p
  fi
done
```

the file contains about 65 or so hostnames. I'm just trying to check if disk usage is less than 85% across all hosts.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicates, this is also covered in [BashFAQ #89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly suggest replacing `cat "$filename" | while ...` with `while ...; done <filename`. Avoids [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) issues. And you might also run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and apply the quoting issues it suggests (even `echo $p` isn't safe; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: what are some examples of your osts file? This script looks like its stuck trying render hosts #1